# Xcode 4 stuck on "Scanning for working copies"

Tags: xcode4

I just archived and submitted a project.  When I go back to open the project it hangs on "scanning for working copies."  I can navigate around but am unable to view the project files.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871096/xcode-stuck-on-loading-revision-and-scanning-for-working-copies-when-usin/11902861#11902861

Answer (score 2):

It is really just a linking problem.

Select your project and make sure you have 'Identity and Type' open. This is in the right side Editor bar(toggle open and closed with 'View' button).

You can change your Location and Full Path there. You just need to check that your project is linked to the correct directories.

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and delete the whole file and paste it in some other directory (or I guess you can put in same directory). Now open it again. I also had same problem. Actually my project was in SVN, so I deleted the directory and again checked out the entire file and opened it again. Now at least that error message is gone.

I am also new to xcode(4.3) .. sorry if my english is not good ...

Answer (score 0):

Open up a more trusted Source Control App, like SourceTree, and refresh all of your working copies, then Xcode, will behave.

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to result from incorrect linking or damage to the version control repository.  Other answers suggested deleting the repository or removing it from xcode under the Window -> Organise menu.  I suggest you try these options and the suggestions in the other answers.  However none of these worked for me and my xcode was still displaying the "scanning for working copies" message and intermittently locking up.

Deleting xcode from the Applications folder and reinstalling it from the app store then importing my project fixed the issue for me.  I also suggest you dont use version control for your project unless you really need it.