# Xcode: How to get commits correctly organized for shared files?

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

My current Xcode project uses some files that I originally created in another Xcode project and added to the current project.

I have edited some of those added files from within the current project and would like to commit them using source control. However, when I go to the organizer, those commits are showing up under the project in which they were originally created, not my current active project.

Is there a way to get these commits to show up within my current active project as well? If not, do I simply have to move these files out of their "old" project files and into my current active project (and then re-add those files back into the old projects)? It seems illogical that these commits would only show up under the old projects if both projects are using these files and if the commits affect both projects.

(n.b. This question is a follow-up / related to the following question...hopefully answering this question will also answer my previous question: [Xcode stuck on "Loading Revision" and "Scanning for working copies..." when using Source Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871096/xcode-stuck-on-loading-revision-and-scanning-for-working-copies-when-usin))

Comment: The smartest thing would be to *copy* those files into your new project and then reset the file paths (via the file inspector) in your project to point within your own project's hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did not copy the files over to the new project directory, then they are still going to be under source control of the other project as that is where they exist on disk. You will either need to copy the files over to the new project, or make your other xcode project a git submodule of the project you are working with. That way you only have to update the code once and it should be reflected in the other project in both code bases.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Thank you, AC Macalister! I will have to learn about submodules. For now, I moved the files over to the new project (since I don't need the old projects anymore) and updated file locations.