# When Xcode is stuck on "Loading Revision" why does deleting yourproject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata fix it?

Tags: xcode

I'm writing openFrameworks code in Xcode and recently opened Xcode to find it stuck on "Loading Revision."

This was problematic because I couldn't reach the build settings; When I clicked on my project tree I got the error that it was "not under source control."

I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871096/xcode-stuck-on-loading-revision-and-scanning-for-working-copies-when-usin) in another stackoverflow thread which said to delete the contents of `yourproject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace` which for me was simply `contents.xcworkspacedata`

That worked! But I want to know *why* that worked, besides magic.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any direct answer to this question, or even clear answers on the description of xcworkspace from various [threads](http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2011/Mar/msg00286.html) I've found.

I want more general insight into what's happening rather than a very useful short term fix but no greater lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem when trying to compare versions in the version editor. The problem goes away when switching to either the standard or assistant editor.

It seems to me that the "magic" here is simply that by deleting the contents of yourproject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace the project is forced to close. When you re-open the project, it opens in the standard editor.

So, I could be wrong, but I think that the problem is in the version editor. What the problem actually is... I don't know. This also explains why there is an error "not under source control" when the project tree is clicked.